# jquery mouseover and mouseout on multiple contents and buttons

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

tried many things, but cannot get it to work. when user mouse over to first button, the first content will show up. my code is working now, but when i mouseout the button, all content within the page are gone.

also when i mouse out the button, i want some default content show up.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my javascript

```
$(".button").mouseover(function(){      
    $(".content-container").eq(depends on parent number).append("<div class='content'>" + value + '</div>');
}).mouseout(function(){$(".content").remove();});
```

to make my question clear.
when user mouse event to button in .parent one, it will only remove content or add content to the parent one container.

and i also need a solution to set up a default content when they mouseout, otherwise the content div will be blank.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What effect do you want after you mouseout?

Comment: just want the content replace with "default content". and when mouseover, it will show the content according to the button it relates to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here are a few things that might help:

Use classes for styling, not identifying.

If you have sections of html you want to change put inside a

```
<div id="my_default_content">..some content...</div>
```

Now suppose you have a button and you want to remove the content:

```
<button onclick="function() {$('#my_default_content').css('visibility', 'none')}">Clear</button>
```

Or you could make content visible again by setting 'visibility' to 'visible'. If you want the div to NOT take up space, set 'display' to 'none'.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var content = $('<div />', {text: this.value, 'class': 'content'});
        $(this).siblings('.content-container').html(content);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var default = $('<div />', {text: 'Hello Kitty'});
        $(this).siblings('.content-container').html(default);
    } 
});
```

Comment: my problem is not with mouseover and mouseout i guess, i just want the .remove() function remove only the content in its parent, not remove the content from the whole page.

Comment: And this should do exactly that ?